# Androidのpush通知を複数表示する方法について

Tags: android, push-notification

Androidのpush通知を複数回受信した時に、通知エリアに受信した回数分表示する方法について、ご教授頂きたく質問させて頂きました。

Androidmanifest.xmlの<application>の中に下記を入れると良いという記述を見つけたのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。

```
<meta-data android:name="notificationOverlap" android:value="1"/>
```

こちら、 `notificationOverlap` に `1`を設定すると良さそうだったのですが、何か他に対応する必要があるのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。

何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

参考にしたサイト
http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/sdkguide/android/push.html
http://qiita.com/Moris_Mk-II/items/d4852407261f881c2753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちら、自己解決出来ました。

```
<meta-data android:name="notificationOverlap" android:value="1"/>
```

は、niftyクラウドというサービスで、複数通知を表示させたい場合の設定方法でした。。

実装は `NotificationManager#notify` の引数に渡す `id` をユニークにする事によって、複数回push通知を受信した時に、通知エリアにその同じ数だけ、表示がされるようになりました。

[NotificationManager.html#notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))